# Add NSDefaults string into InAppSettingsKit

Tags: iphone, ios, inappsettingskit

I want to be able to change the `DefaultValue` of one of a `UITableView` cell in the Settings.bundle. I mainly want to put this...

`userEmail = [defaults objectForKey:@"username"];`

...into the plist.

I am doing this because I want my app to display the user's email in the settings so that they know what account they are using.

Here is part of the plist data that I want changed.

```
<dict>
            <key>IASKTextAlignment</key>
            <string>IASKUITextAlignmentRight</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>EMAIL</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>email</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Email</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
```

How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically change the plist in the Settings.bundle because it belongs to the read-only (as far as sandboxing goes) app bundle.

What you probably want to do is to modify the current value using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"the username" forKey:@"username"]` in your `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or somewhere else in your startup process.

Then the change will be reflected in IASK and the system settings.